# Semantic of SQL Query for summing up values

Tags: sql-server, query, sum

I am new to SQL and not getting even simple things. I am wondering if the following code does not add a real column?

```
select * 
sum(value) over (partition by prename order by NumberOfDays) SumValue
from (select *, row_number() over (order by NumberOfDays) rn from 
tablenames) as t
order by rn
```

I thought with this code I would create a new column called SumValue. When I execute the code above it works fine and the column SumValue with all its values is shown but when I try to calcualte with this column, let's say:

```
ALTER TABLE tablenames
ADD AvValue float; 
UPDATE [DatabaseXY].[dbo].[tablenames]
SET AvH = [SumValue]/[NumberOfDays]
```

SSMS tells me that SumValue is an invalid column name. Why is that? Even if I refresh or restart SSMS and look into the object explorer there is no column called SumValue..
I guess with my presented code I only create kinda temporary columns but how do I add those values to a real column?

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

No column is added to the table during the select. Adding columns to a table is usually restricted to a lot fewer people, than those that are allowed to select from a table. You can do this as:

```
ALTER TABLE tablenames
    ADD AvValue float;

MERGE INTO tablenames x
USING (
    select t.* 
         , sum(value) over (partition by prename order by NumberOfDays) SumValue
    from tablenames t
) y
    ON x.<key> = y.<key>
WHEN MATCHED THEN
    UPDATE SET x.AvValue = y.SumValue/y.NumberOfDays
```

All untested since I don't know what the key for tablenames is.

You can probably calculate AvValue directly in the USING clause, but I'll leave that as an exercise.

EDIT: The implementation of MERGE in SQL-server seems to have several problems, see [use-caution-with-sql-servers-merge-statement/](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3074/use-caution-with-sql-servers-merge-statement/) (link provided by [Aaron Bertrand](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/1186/aaron-bertrand) in comment. Using an update instead would be something like (still untested):

```
WITH y AS (
    SELECT t.* 
     , SUM(value) OVER (PARTITION BY prename 
                        ORDER BY NumberOfDays) SumValue
    FROM tablenames t
)
UPDATE y
SET y.AvValue = y.SumValue/y.NumberOfDays;
```

Comment: Just please [be very cautious with `MERGE`](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3074/use-caution-with-sql-servers-merge-statement/), especially when you don't really get any benefit from using it (this is an `UPDATE` and nothing more).

Comment: Phew, quite impressive list of bugs. I usually dont use SQL server, so I had no idea. Thanks for pointing that out

Comment: @Lennart, `MERGE` is hard for DBMS developers. Now you know why PostgreSQL hasn't implemented it even in the latest version.

Comment: I'm not convinced that introducing an  extension to compensate for the lack of a standard construction is the way to go though. Another open source alternative has a history of just that... ;-)

Comment: Thank you so much! As I am pretty new to SQL I am a bit confused now. So I better dont use MERGE but rather UPDATE? How should I implement it? Sorry for my dumb question..

Comment: @Lennart - not sure how T-SQL's extended UPDATE syntax compensates for lacking a 'standard construction' that only existed as such a decade or so after the T-SQL feature was created... That said, better use a standard UPDATE with CTE.